# Source file doesn't work while updating it

Tags: php, ftp

A source file is not working while updating it via FTP.

During that time, I get errors in the PHP log which says that a function in that file is undefined. It lasts just for a second but it sufficient to get errors from some clients.

I'm very surprised, I believed that the system keeps in memory old files before uploading was finished. My system is CentOS 6.5 and uploading is performed by FileZilla last version. The source is encrypted by sourceguardian.

What I can do to avoid this temporary failure?

Comment: pls post the exact error mes

Comment: no need for any error messages, the behavior is very clear. While being uploaded, the file is not available. You can't really prevent it as far as I know. Think at a byte to byte level, **the file is being rewritten on the disc**, how could it not be unavailable?

Answer (score 1):

That's a general problem. The FTP protocol does not support any standard file locking mechanism.

It's possible to workaround that by uploading a file to a temporary file name; and rename it to a final name, once the upload is done only.

In case the SFTP protocol is an option for your, [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) SFTP/FTP client can do this transparently for any upload. Unfortunately, it supports that with the SFTP protocol only, not with the FTP. See [Automatic Resume / Transfer to Temporary Filename](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/resume#automatic) in WinSCP documentation.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*